# What is the difference between exiting a datagridview cell edit by clicking away and by pressing enter?

Tags: c#, datagridview

The first two lines of the CellEndEdit event of my datagridview are:

```
if (dgvOptionsData.SortedColumn == null)
            dgvOptionsData.Sort(dgvOptionsData.Columns["GroupNumber"], 0);
```

The DataGridView is bound to a DataTable.

I am getting a reentrancy error (Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function.) at the Sort call ONLY when I enter the CellEndEdit event by clicking away from the cell. If I enter the event by pressing enter I do no get this error. I also don't get the error once gridview is sorted, even if I am editing a value in the  sorted column.

I have since restructured my code so that I am not using the CellEndEdit event and thus this error is not a problem any more but I would like to understand what was happening and why. If you have any insights please let me know.

Thanks
Dan

Comment: Dan, if you remember your solution, I'd be interested to hear it.  I just solved this very solution by moving all my code from the CellEndEdit event to the CellValueChanged event.  Is that what you did or was it something else?  (CellValueChanged fires right before CellEndEdit and doesn't cause the reentrant problem.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a subtle difference between actions that you take to commit cell edit. Basically by clicking away you understand clicking on another cell of data grid view. This action is handled by grid view in this manner:

- event handler

  - select cell as active (as argument clicked cell for example (1,1))

    - commit edited cell

      - CellEndEdit handler (user code)

        - Sort grid

          - select cell as active (as argument special value for no cell (-1,-1))
            this throws an error because of reenter to this method

Note that if you click other control (not data grid) your sorting will work fine.

Committing changes by Enter key simply invokes select cell as active after CellEndEdit handler is finished.

Comment: This is very interesting, how do you find this out? Is this in the documentation somewhere? Or can you debug through and see it?

Comment: If you look at exception stack trace you will see methods names that are called especially `SetCurrentCellAddressCore` that occurs twice. Then I've looked at its code with ILSpy and saw `throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString("DataGridView_SetCurrentCellAddressCoreNotReentrant"));`. I presume that this line that throws in this scenario.
According to msdn there is a way to debug [framewok](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410.aspx) but I haven't done it myself.

Answer (score 0):

`DataGridView` raises this exception to prevent and infinite loop.  This will occur whenever you try to change the active cell while an operation is being performed on the currently-active cell.  You must enter the `CellEndEdit` event because sorting changes the contents of the cells, and you are also editing one of the cells.  Any operation that changes the active cell while the `DataGridView` is using it will trigger this exception.

Comment: But that does not explain why it worked when I pressed enter, but not when I clicked away. The main question is what is the difference between those two.