# Datagridview sorting column based on matching string

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sorting, datagridview

I have a datagridview that I would like to have rows sorted based on the portion of a string entered from a user. The entered string is compared with all of the strings in a particular column. For instance, if I gave "comp" as the search word, the program would try to compare the search word with the strings on first column and sort the rows in a descending order which starts with "comp", such as "compare", "composition", "computer" etc. Rest of the words that do not match is either left alone or sorted in an alphabetical order (whichever is easier).

In LINQ, I am aware that you can apply the following code to achieve what you wanted with a string array:

```
var sortedWords = words.Where(x => x.Contains("comp"))
                       .OrderByDescending(x => x);
```

How can I achieve the same thing in Datagridview as I need to have the rows sorted, not just the items inside a particular column?

Edit:

The following code is giving a System.InvalidOperationException. (SetCurrentCellAddressCore is being called twice)

```
    private void DGVPointCtrl_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        MatchComparer mc = new MatchComparer();
        DGVPointCtrl.Sort(mc); //Error
    }
```

I'm probably doing something wrong but I'm not sure why. Here is the code that programatically adds the rows for testing purposes:

```
private void BtnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                DGVPointCtrl.Rows.Clear();
                int mainIndex = CmbMainDevice.SelectedIndex;
                int subIndex = CmbSubDevice.SelectedIndex;
                DDCDAO ddcdao = new DDCDAO(DDCGlobal.ddcEngineIP, ddc.Ip);
                string pointListType;
                object rs;

                //Currently only supports IO DDC Request
                //TO DO: Change DDCDAO to send proper subdevice requests

                if (mainIndex == 0) //IO
                {
                    #region Main Device: IO
                }


                //First row is for searching items
                DGVPointCtrl.Rows.Add(new DataGridViewRow());
                for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    DGVPointCtrl.Rows.Add(new DataGridViewRow());
                    DGVPointCtrl.Rows[i].ReadOnly = true;
                }
                DGVPointCtrl.Columns[0].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic;
                DGVPointCtrl.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.Font =
                new Font(DGVPointCtrl.DefaultCellStyle.Font, FontStyle.Italic | FontStyle.Bold);

                if (subIndex == 1) //BI
                {
                    PointDGVColumnGenerate("IO_BI");

                }
                else if (subIndex == 2) //BO
                {
                    PointDGVColumnGenerate("IO_BO");
                }
                else if (subIndex == 3) //AI
                {
                    PointDGVColumnGenerate("IO_AI");
                }
                else if (subIndex == 4) //AO
                {
                    PointDGVColumnGenerate("IO_AO");
                }

                DGVPointCtrl.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value = "IO12314";
                DGVPointCtrl.Rows[2].Cells[0].Value = "IO21948";
                DGVPointCtrl.Rows[3].Cells[0].Value = "IO28194";
                DGVPointCtrl.Rows[4].Cells[0].Value = "VP12984";
                DGVPointCtrl.Rows[2].Cells[1].Value = "asdf";

                #endregion
            }
            catch
            {
            }
      }

    private void PointDGVColumnGenerate(string key)
    {
        int colCount = 0;
        DGVColumnTable.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < COL_MAX; i++)
        {
            DGVPointCtrl.Columns[i].HeaderText = "   ";
            DGVPointCtrl.Columns[i].Visible = true;
        }

        foreach (string s in UIConstant.DDCPCtrlListColumnText[key])
        {
            DGVPointCtrl.Columns[colCount].HeaderText = s;
            DGVColumnTable.Add(DGVPointCtrl.Columns[colCount]);
            colCount++;
        }
    }
```

Edit2:

```
public class MatchComparer : IComparer
{
    private static IComparer defaultComparer = new CaseInsensitiveComparer();
    int IComparer.Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        DataGridViewRow xr = (DataGridViewRow)x;
        DataGridViewRow yr = (DataGridViewRow)y;

        string xs = "";
        string ys = "";
        try
        {
            xs = xr.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        try
        {
            ys = yr.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        }
        catch
        {
        }

        if (HasMatch(xs) && !HasMatch(ys)) return -1;
        else if (!HasMatch(xs) && HasMatch(ys)) return 1;
        else return defaultComparer.Compare(xs, ys);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible only if you are populating the grid yourself as opposed to binding it to the database.

Set `DataGridViewColumn.SortMode` to [`Programmatic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumnsortmode.aspx).

Use [`DataGridView.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wstxtkxs.aspx) to impose a comparer like this:

```
public class MatchComparer : IComparer  {
     int IComparer.Compare(object x, object y)  {
         if (HasMatch(x) && !HasMatch(y)) return -1;
         else if (!HasMatch(x) && HasMatch(y)) return 1;
         else return defaultComparer.Compare(x, y);
     }

     private bool HasMatch(object x) {
         return x is string && ((string)x).StartsWith("comp");
     }

     private static IComparer defaultComparer = new CaseInsensitiveComparer();
}
```

Comment: The code has some compiler errors.. actually a lot of errors. IComparer needs to have a specified type, defaultComparer.compare doesn't take objects as parameter, defaultComparer cannot have CaseInsensitiveComparer assigned.

Comment: Never mind it works as soon as I include the collections namespace!

Comment: @SokwhanHuh - That's it.  I just edited away a few typos, most importantly the swapped arguments when calling the `defaultComparer`.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this only sorts the rows with the specified columns. I need the entire rows to be sorted. (I have the first column labeled as "ID" and rest of them are just entries that describes the mentioned ID. It becomes pointless if only the IDs are sorted without the items following the sorted row)

Comment: @SokwhanHuh - This sorts one grid.  There is no way to sort columns within grid independently of each other.

Comment: Hmm it is still not working for me. Could you take a look at the edited portion of my code and see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @SokwhanHuh - This depends on where you set the sort.  I'd expect it on an UI event outside of the grid, e.g., the search dialog.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/9770814/1235565 (I'd like to learn how those reentrancy issues exactly arise so I just offered a bounty there.)

Comment: I tried to invoke the sort function on a button click, but instead of a reentrancy issue, I've actually got another exception on this line:

else return defaultComparer.Compare(x, y);

It says that at least one of the instance has to be created of type "IComparable"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13363/discussion-between-jirka-hanika-and-sokwhan-huh)

Comment: Stack overflowchat is blocked from where I work :( My company doesn't allow access to it

Comment: @SokwhanHuh - I was just saying that I had been assuming that the data would arrive as strings. But they are some different type which does not implement IComparable. Can you please debug that out? For example, MessageBox(typeof(x)).  (Alternately, you could forget about `defaultComparer` altogether and simply return zero.)

Comment: You're right! It's returning the entire row (MessageBox.Show(x.ToString() + y.ToString() is displaying DataGridViewRow {Index = 0}, DataGridView {Index = 2}). So in this case.. I'd have to explicitly cast x,y to DataGridViewRow, then compare the strings that's inside the cells? Actually.. I'm not even sure why it's returning Index of 0 and 2

Comment: @SokwanHuh - Yes, extract the strings first thing in your comparer.

Comment: I have edited my OP as to what you suggested. I've came across a problem where I am getting a nullreferenceexception on where I assign xs, and xy. The above solution, albeit not elegant at all, works for my purposes. I'm actually wondering why I'm getting a null reference exception in the first place.

Comment: @SokwhanHuh - `xr.Cells[0].Value` may well be `Nothing` for some rows that have no data in the column.